# How to collapse all procedures (code folding) in Oracle Sql Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Visual Studio I could hit Ctrl+M twice and I could just see a list of function names.  Is there an equivalent to this in Sql Developer?  When I right click in the code folding bar, nothing happens.

Answer (score 12):

First, enable:
Tools > Preferences > Code Editor: Display > Show Code Folding Margin

Then, right click in the margin and choose the Collapse options:
[image: Right click in code folding margin, choose "Collapse procedure declarations/bodies"]
(This is Oracle Sql Developer 3.1.07)

In my case, I had to restart Sql Developer for the right-click context menu to appear.

Comment: How are blocks of SQL code detected? I'm not using procedures, I have a massive SQL query with sub queries, and SQL Developer only collapses the first few lines of the query before the first parenthesis of a sub-query.